# Why would I return an item from a function if I append to a global array within the function?

Tags: swift, return-value

I'm writing an application from a tutorial that is a to-do list but I'm a little confused on why its setup this way and could use other perspectives.

Why would I return an item from a function if I append to a global array within the function? Why wouldn't we just query the array for this item. I'm not catching onto why this item is being returned or how its being used.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ItemStore {

    var allItems =  [Item]()

    func createItem() -> Item {
        //use a constant to initialize a new item using the Item class's syntax
        let newItem = Item.init(random: true)
        //now append it to this class's allItems array
        allItems.append(newItem)
        //now according to this function we need to return an Item object.  Now return newItem....but why are we returning it if we just appended it to the allItems array??  Can't we just query the array for this item?  I wonder how this returned item is going to be used now
        return newItem
    }

    //now I'm going to add a designated initializer to this class which will add five random items to the allItems array....arrgghh, whhyyy??
    init() {
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            createItem()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From which tutorial does that come from? We cannot *guess* why somebody designed it that way, knowing the context might give a clue.

Comment: @MartinR Its from the Big Nerd Ranch's iOS programming 5th edition book.  I hope I'm not giving the text a bad rep as I wanted to understand it before moving forward.  Its a great book, just wanted to understand the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `createItem` function should not do any appending. It should do just what is says - create and return a new item. Let the caller determine what to do with the new item. I would refactor your code as:

```
class ItemStore {
    var allItems = [Item]()

    func createItem() -> Item {
        let newItem = Item(random: true)

        return newItem
    }

    init() {
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            let item = createItem()
            allItems.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can refactor as:

```
class ItemStore {
    var allItems = [Item]()

    func loadItems() {
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            let item = Item(random: true)
            allItems.append(item)
        }
    }

    init() {
        loadItems()
    }
}
```

It's best to avoid non-obvious side effects. It's not obvious that a method named `createItem` would also add that newly created item to some list. Keep methods focused. Put functionality where it belongs.

Comment: it's not about refactoring it's about Why declared like this

Answer (score 1):

One reason is to be able to setup other properties in the class.

Let's assume the class has an `index` property und you want to assign consecutive indices.

```
init() {
    for i in 0..<5 {
        let newItem = createItem()
        newItem.index = i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a wrong approach the developer may want to use the added item directly like this

```
let store = ItemStore()

let item = store.createItem()
```

this may confuses with how `init` method is written put he may want the function to do more than one thing